# How to extract side-view outline (e.g. top view) of a 3D object to 2D surface?

Tags: mesh, particles, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface, shrinkwrap

I want to make some 2D version of 3D particles. I used to shrinkWrap the 3D mesh to a plan, and draw NURBS curve manually along the boundary. However it is too time-consuming!

[image]

Is there any easy way to extract the 2D curve, i.e. the orange outline shown above, or clean the internal vertices of a shrink-wrapped mesh?

**Update**: 
The knife project tool is not usable in my case, as the mesh consists of 20k+ vertices. The blender seems "dead" when using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a complex 3d object into a 2d contour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101525/turning-a-complex-3d-object-into-a-2d-contour)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example/

Comment: The knife project tool is so slow! I tested it with a coarse mesh of 6000 vertices, but no response for few minutes.

Comment: Could you just use a BoolTool Intersect with a simple plane sharing same center? I don't see much of a problem here for me, but I am not sure about your computer specs being a limitation with your mesh object resolutions....

Comment: How about rendering this object with the simplest emission material and ortho camera. Then convert image to .svg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bmesh Approach**

- Projecting onto a plane such that `proj` is our vector normal to the
  plane and the bounding box center is on the plane.
- Split mesh into two sets of vertices those with normals pointing
  towards and away from `proj`
- Project them onto the two planes each side of projection plane[image] *Local Y projection of random icosphere "flatrock" showing intermediate result with `scale_factor` thickness 1, and silhouette edge mesh in orange*
- Bisect    the new flat ended mesh, keeping only the bisection result.

Test Script, projects using the local Y axis producing a front on silhouette mesh that can be converted to curve. Adjust `proj` ([could use 3d view matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23028/15543))  and `scale_factor` which controls the thickness of flattened mesh.

Edit: Updated for 2.8. For prior version see [revision 5](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/121732/5)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
viewlayer = context.view_layer
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
scale_factor = 0.1
c  = sum((Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box), Vector()) / 8   

proj = Vector((0, 1, 0)).normalized()
T = Matrix.Translation(-c)
S = Matrix.Scale(0, 4, proj)
verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.normal.dot(proj) > 0]
bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=S, verts=verts, 
        space=Matrix.Translation(-c - scale_factor * proj))
bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=S, verts=list(set(bm.verts) - set(verts)), 
        space=Matrix.Translation(-c + scale_factor * proj))

#bm.to_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:],
        plane_co=c,
        plane_no=proj,
        clear_inner=True,
        clear_outer=True)

copy = ob.copy()
sil = bpy.data.meshes.new("silhouette")
copy.data = sil
scene.collection.objects.link(copy)
viewlayer.objects.active = copy
copy.select_set(True)
bm.to_mesh(sil)
```

[image]
*This time showing result of looping on 3 principal local axes `for proj in Matrix.Identity(3):`*

[image]
*Y projection of Suzanne.  Showing how backfaces on opposite side of planes create some internal geometry which could be tested for and ignored*
[image]
*result of script on object with 60K+ verts ran in a couple of seconds on old computer*

**A projection Approach.**

In an answer to [Perspective Flatten Geometry by Shrinkwrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159914/perspective-flatten-geometry-by-shrinkwrap) have flattened selected mesh objects onto the camera frustum. Script in answer is "PROJ" in gif.

[image]

To take those objects an limited dissolve edges, to get result as shown in GIF.  Once again the concavities and non manifold nature of suzanne has left artifacts.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
for ob in context.selected_objects:
    me = ob.data
    ob.display_type = 'WIRE'
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    #bm.normal_update()
    bmesh.ops.dissolve_limit(
            bm,
            edges=bm.edges,
            verts=bm.verts,
            angle_limit=.1
            )
            
    bm.to_mesh(me)
```

One potential fix would be, if not reduced to 2 ngons like like the cube and cone, could test by projecting back onto the original

**Shrinkwrap Approach**

Won't bother scripting this one for now. Theoretically another  way to get the outline of a mesh.

Add a plane or grid, sub'd it and project shrinkwrap it onto target. Use bounding box dimensions to get size
[image]

This will give a "pixelated" outline.

[image]

Any quads of evaluated plane with no verts on suzanne can be removed. Others can be manipulated roblox style depending on how many verts are still on plane (1, 2 or 3) to "anti-alias" outline.

The remaining boundary edges will be an approximation to outline.

Comment: Can you please refine the 3D mesh into ~30000 vertices, and test the performance?

Comment: Very clever indeed,,,

Answer (score 5):

Did you try freestyle - export to svg?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/render/freestyle/export_svg.html

[image]

Comment: What I want to do is to extract a clean 2D mesh.

Comment: You could then import the SVG file.  It's at least worth trying and comparing the results to other approaches.

Comment: theres the non blender way, it may apply.
render your image shadeles with alpha background
inkskape [ https://inkscape.org/es/release/0.92.3/  ]
inkskape have a function to convert bitmaps to svg curves
check this: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMewvFYPOdM]
then import it back as inkscape saves svg files.

Comment: I think this is a very clean approach.. getting Freestyle to do all the work.. and you can tune it by adjusting segment lengths, simplifying curvature, using all the modifiers available - all within Blender.

Comment: if you dont need it explicitelly as an svg curve. why not to try the boolean modifier to extract a section of your mesh. Use a plane to get the intersection section you want. 
look at this may be this is what you need 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEudXbZQzIA