# Is it possible to create a silhouette edge of a mesh in Blender?

Tags: camera

I want to be able to create a silhouette edge from a chosen point on any given mesh. Essentially, the silhouette edge is a 3D curve made up of points on the mesh whose tangent planes intersect with a chosen perspective point. I'm not just looking for a silhouette to surround the mesh from all perspectives. I want to be able to create a silhouette edge from one perspective, and then look at the curve created from the previous viewpoint in different viewpoints.

This is a demonstration of what it would look like with a cube.
The silhouette edge take from perspective A:

[image]

This is the same silhouette edge viewed from a different perspective B:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101525/turning-a-complex-3d-object-into-a-2d-contour https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example

Comment: I'm not looking for a 2D projection. The silhouette edge is a 3D curve that runs along the mesh.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of your setup ?

Comment: I don't really have a setup in Blender, I started using it recently. This is an example of a silhouette edge. Again, it is a 3D curve, not a 2D projection. https://image.slidesharecdn.com/gtc2009openglkilgard-091008215235-phpapp01/95/opengl-32-and-more-42-728.jpg?cb=1255392697

Comment: Isn't it what Line Art does? 

Comment: I think an important distinction is having a visual effect of a silhouette and calculating geometry of the silhouette...

Answer (score 1):

The easierst way to do this is using a Grease Pencil object. Here is my proposal in Blender 3.3 how to do this in a few steps:

https://youtu.be/isZ31C1NYtQ

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a silhouette edge using [freestyle](https://artisticrender.com/a-guide-to-blender-freestyle-rendering-with-eevee-and-cycles/)

First you need to enable Freestyle in `Properties Editor` > `Render` tab > `Freestyle` panel:

[image: freestyle panel]

In `Properties Editor` > `Layer` tab > `Freestyle line set` panel, you can choose how the line is formed. I.E. you can set it to display silhouette only:

[image: line set]

More about it: [A guide to Blender freestyle rendering with Eevee and Cycles](https://artisticrender.com/a-guide-to-blender-freestyle-rendering-with-eevee-and-cycles/)